# How to display timers in a uitableview?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uilabel, nstimer

I am trying to make an app where two people can message each other, but after 30 seconds that a message is sent I want to delete the message. The messages are being displayed in a UITableView. I am having a UILabel display how much time is left in each UITableViewCell, but I was wondering if there is any way to do this without having to call [self.tableView reloadData] every second. Any other ways of going about this?

Thanks so much,

zweg25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload cell individually by calling

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete some rows in tableview programmically, you can use this method in tableview:

```
- (void) deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)rows withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

But you must delete the items in your datasource before you call this method to refresh your tablview.

Hope that my answer can help you :)